# Django Admin Login page got messed up. (After git pull maybe? I am not sure)

Tags: django, github

[image]

I am not sure when did this happen, I seldom check my admin page while coding. I have been messing around with github and git bash to be familiarized with things so that I can work with a team environment. Is this because someone messed with this page on another branch and pushed changes to master branch? Anyone knows how to fix this?

UPDATE: It is working fine with my Microsoft Edge (Internet Explorer).

- I checked my other projects and found out they got messed up too. Seems like the problem is with the Google Chrome browser like someone said on the comments below.

Comment: did you check with different browsers ?

Comment: it is working fine with my Micrisoft Edge (Internet Explorer). Any ideas what casued this problem?

Comment: I too had faced this issue. as far as I read people say it was because some extension messed up django.. but I tried removing all extensions but still the same issue. Funny part was it became normal when I deleted and reinstalled Chrome for 2nd time. Note that first time there was no change. This was my experience.

Comment: Ok thank you sir, I will try to do the same thing you did.